# Window borders look weird after installing nvidia drivers on Plasma 5.16

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, kde

Please help me, before I go **mad**!

I'm running Kubuntu 19.10 (Plasma 5.16.5), and the first thing I did was install nVidia drivers (nvidia-340). Everything seemed to be normal (using the default theme that comes with Kubuntu), but when I switched to a different theme from the "Look and Feel" menu found in System Settings, something odd happened:

I noticed that, **on minimized windows**, the top border looks slightly smaller than it's intended size: 
[Exhibit #1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g79e.png)

Pay attention to the top borders on the Konsole, where the title is. See how it looks weird and, like, shrunk?
Weird thing is that when in fullscreen, it looks perfect: [Exhibit 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb22V.png)

**Things to keep in mind:**

1. I went back to Noveau for testing, and it works wonderfully. However, of course I'd rather use nVidia's drivers.
2. My graphics card is a GeForce 310M.
3. I'm using a laptop (it uses the nVidia card and an Intel Core i3).

So... I'm at a loss for words. I tried to tweak as much as I could from the Appearance sub-menus, to no luck... I read something about nVidia doing weird things to the font's DPI, I tried changing it to no avail.

I'm suspecting I'm using the wrong nVidia driver? I just installed the one the system recommended after running `ubuntu-drivers devices`.

Hope someone can lend me a hand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is pretty awkward! I remembered the Composition tab in **System Settings > Display and Monitor > Compositor** and changed the rendering backend from **OpenGL 2.0 to OpenGL 3.1**. Did a **reboot**, and everything works as intended with nVidia drivers! [Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF3xD.png) [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emgrh.png)

Pretty embarassing, but I hope this helps someone out there!